# Sharing an internet connection two times (ad-hoc + second network card sharing)

Tags: internet-connection, ps3, ad-hoc-network, internet-sharing

First, here's my setup : I have a computer with 1 WiFi network card and 2 ethernet network card.

My internet connection is received by one of my ethernet network card. I've been temporary sharing it with my girlfriend with an AD-HOC wireless connection sharing using my WiFi card.

Now I'd like to share it another time but this time using my second ethernet network card so my PS3 could get internet too in the same place. (Because PS3 can't connect to Windows' AD-HOC shared internet... argh).

I've been doing it with a second router but two routers seem a bit of an overkill for this purpose. This is only for little internet sharing sessions so it doesn't have to be very stable...

I've been trying to do it but I can't seems to understand how, when I plug my PS3 to my second ethernet network card it goes "Identifying.... Network cable unplugged... Identifying... again and again..."

Any tips, advice or idea about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try creating a network bridge between the three NICs.

Comment: I tried it and it says so: "To create a Network Bridge, you must select at least two LAN or High-Speed connections that are not being used by Internet Connection Sharing." One of them is the internet connection :\

Comment: [Disable internet connection sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Disable-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing) on all of the adapters first.

Comment: I did it on the three of them. The ad-hoc wifi is still working but my PS3 is telling me that it is unable to get an IP address :S

Comment: Did you reboot the PS3? If you have, set a manual ip address on the PS3. IP address: whatever your "network" is using, e.g. `192.168.1.5` Subnet mask: most likely `255.255.255.0` Default gateway: blank

Comment: It almost work! I had to put gateway and the primary dns infos so I put 192.168.1.1 (which is my router address) in both fields. As weird as it sounds, the connection test gets the local ip, but fails at internet connection and psn connection. And weirder : I can go online using the internet browser! :\ But can't sign in on PSN.

Comment: God damn Sony and PSN!!! They're down again! So nevermind, I guess everything will be alright when it'll be back on! Please post an answer and I'll mark you as correct! Thanks a lot for helping me out!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First [Disable internet connection](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Disable-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing) sharing on all of the adapters.
- Create a network bridge between the three NICs.
- Set a manual IP address on the PS3.

  - IP address: whatever your "network" is using, e.g. 192.168.1.5
  - Subnet mask: most likely 255.255.255.0
  - Default gateway: 192.168.1.1
  - DNS server: 8.8.8.8
- Reboot the PS3